# How can I configure the .htaccess file so that it takes care of both the Angular routes and HTTPS redirecting?

Tags: angular, .htaccess, https, routes

We have and Angular app (front-end only) hosted on a CPanel hosting. I changed the .htaccess file to account for Angular routes.

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>

# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

The problem is, when I add the code for redirecting to https, it shows the error 'too many redirects'. It seems that I can only have on of https and routes, despite both being very important. Also, I know that this question has been asked before, but the answer to that did not help me.

Also, I am open to using redirects or something else...

**UPDATE**

I changed the code to this:

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]


# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>

# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^playbrackets\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.playbrackets\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/playbrackets\.com\/index.html" [R=301,L]
```

It redirects to https some of the times, especially in Incognito window, or when I clear the browser cache. It doesnt actually FORCE the redirection.

Comment: Could you please do add your other htaccess too, I could see you are using inherit option in your rules, please share that htaccess too which will give us understanding of what's going on, thank you.

Comment: Sure, I will. Just so you know, I am very bad in .htaccess stuff, so the inherit line is probably not needed. I'll add the code.

Comment: Can you show the  code you want to add? (the https redirection)

Comment: Actually, I do not know what code to add. I basically need two things to happen. 1) redirect http to https, and 2) make sure the angular routes work in the case of reloading.

Answer (score 0):

---

### Enabling HTTPS redirect in cPanel for all sites

First check if your .htaccess file is in the correct directory.
The following is a generic solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

This block enables rewriting capabilities, verifies that the initial request does not already have a *https://* and rewrites the entire requested URL, replacing *http://* with *https://*

(e.g. *http://example.com/subfolder/index.html* will be replaced with *https://example.com/subfolder/index.html*)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This block works the same way as the previous one, just with the help of a different syntax. It is possible to use either of the above mentioned rewrite rules in order to redirect all sites within cPanel.

Comment: Got this part. However, what should I add for the angular routing system?

Comment: As far as I understand, this should work for angular routes as well, because every url is rewritten to https.

Comment: I checked both, and neither options works for me. Neither do they reroute to https, but the routing system also fails.

Comment: Do you mean angular fails to route, even if it's http?

Comment: It routes. But for example, if I go to app, it opens the app page. It I route to app/home, it does that too. If, however, I reload while in app/home, it does not open it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool tool to help you out here. See [this link](https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/#/generator).

It will help you to generate your htaccess file. The following output should do the trick.The first rewriterule does 301 permanent redirect from http to https. The second first checks for the existence of an actual file or directory. If the request if not for a file or directory, it redirects everything to index.html.

```
# Generated with ngx-htaccess-generator v1.0.7
# https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  
  # Redirection to HTTPS:
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
  
  # Redirection of requests to index.html
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  # Redirect all non-file routes to index.html
  RewriteRule ^(?!.*\.).*$ index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

You can use [madewithlove's htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be) to see whether it works.

Here is the redirect to https:

[image]

Here is the redirect to index.html:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I checked it with the tool, and it says the https redirection worked, but failed to act on the lines that contain the usage of index.html. In reality, it failed on both regards.

Comment: However, from the tool that you suggested for testing, I was able to see that these line `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d` were always showing condition was not met...

Comment: These condition is indeed never met. These are for files like images, javascript files, css. You need these lines in order to serve your images. But for any other request these conditions should not be met and a request to index.html should be made. I will update my answer to show that the rewrite works.